# Elements are stuck in top left corner React/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface, frontend

I am building a simple react page using create-react-app, and having trouble with the layout. My components are nested in App, which is limited to the top of the page.

Here is an image, showing where the elements are and my component tree:

// App

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}
```

//Container

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
```

//Header

```
.loan-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 3;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 2px rgba(180, 180, 180, .3);
    color: white;
    height: 60px;
}
```

//ApplicationContainer

```
.loan-application-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background: white;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 3;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 2px rgba(180, 180, 180, .3);
    color: #005350;
    height: 100px;
    width: 75%;
    top: 100px;
}

.applications {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 2;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 0.32px;;
    border-radius:3;
    justify-content:space-between;
    font-size: 1vw;
    border-color: black;
}

.view-btn {
    height: 30;
    width: 10%;
    background: #005350;
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: white;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Gill Sans';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1vw;
    width: 30%;
    color: #005350;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLDpz.jpg

Comment: Do you use flexbox? `display: block`? Post you CSS related to your elements...

Comment: Added the CSS @zergski

Comment: @zergski Thank you so much. that did get it to the center of the top. One more question, is how I would get that application card to the center, I cant seem to get it seperated from the header.

Comment: No worries, happy to help! I would appreciate if you acceppted my answere though. =) And do you mean center the same element vertically? What solution did you use in your previous problem?

Comment: I used the quick fix -- Im making a page with two of those "application cards" in the center of the page.

Comment: ah ok.. then just add `bottom: 0` and change the 'margin' from `margin: 0 auto;` to `margin: auto` in the same ruleset. Keep in mind it will have an offset by 100px because you have `top: 100px` set. Setting it to zero will center perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.loan-application-container` has a width of `75%`.
There are multiple ways you can go about this. With flexbox, depending on the `flex-direction` property, you can either specify in the parent to `justify-content: center` or `align-items: center` or in the itself `justify-self: center` or `align-self: center` respectivly.

or as a quickfix try `left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0 auto;` in `.loan-application-container` ruleset.